# Launch Final Cut Pro, make a new project and name it with Automator

Tags: applescript, automator

I want to make an Automator app that will do a couple of things for me with Final Cut Pro:

1. I want it to ask me to name a the new project (we will call it *test1*)
2. Then I want it to make a new folder and name it *test1*
3. Then I want it to launch Final Cut Pro and make a new project and name it *test1*

This is what I have accomplished so far:

1. Run AppleScript

   ```
   on run {foldername, parameters}
       display dialog "Please choose name" default answer "untitled"
       set foldername to text returned of result
       return foldername
   end run
   ```
2. Set Value of Variable foldername
3. New Folder foldername
4. Run AppleScript

   ```
   on run {input, parameters}
   application "Final Cut Pro"
   end run
   ```

I just can’t find any script on how to create a new project, let alone name it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any version of Final Cut, but from the [MacScripter search results](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3amacscripter.net+final+cut+pro#q=site%3amacscripter.net+final+cut+pro+project) it appears like at least the older versions weren't scriptable. Anyway, have you looked at its AppleScript dictionary (by e.g. dropping its icon on AppleScript Editor)?

Would it be possible to just copy a template file instead of creating a new project? If so, if you saved a script like this as `/usr/bin/fcpp` and ran `chmod +x /usr/bin/fcpp`, you could create a new project with `fcpp Project name`.

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p ~/Projects/"$*"
cp -r ~/Documents/Test.fcpx ~/"Projects/$*/$*.fcpx"
open ~/"Projects/$*/$*.fcpx"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no coder, but maybe you could do it at the finder level. Duplicate a blank project file, and rename it the input of your dialog box before opening it?